# How do i access ( see ) on server the gps coordinates i have sent to the server from android?

Tags: android, database, gps, save, windows-server-2008

I have already gotten the coordinates and other paramaters i need. i have used this to post to my server:

```
                               String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"speed\":\""+speed+"\"}}";


                                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                                // Post method to send data to server
                                HttpPost post = new HttpPost();


                                try {
                                    post.setURI(new URI("http://10.0.2.15:80"));
                                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                // set your post data inside post method    
                                try {
                                    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                // execute post request here 
                                try {
                                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
                                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

How am i sure it has gotten to the server? How do i see the coordinates on the server?
I want to save the values in a database and work on them.

Answer (score 0):

When server accept your data just save them in database and as result that everything is saved, return the same data(accepted data from your client by server) to your client program.

> Using this method, you will be sure in:

1. Server accept your data
2. Server accept right data
3. Server saved data

> Example:

Assume that I want to send `'Name = Michael'` parameter to Server. When server accept parameter name i just save it in database and return the same parameter back to client ->`'Name = Michael'`.So, you can be sure that server get parameter.

Comment: but how do i confirm that it has gotten to server?

Comment: As I understand, you want to know whether server gets data from client or not, right? If so, just send back what you received! May be i misunderstood smth. Can you write more details or give example.